# What is the best way to implement shorting(Multiple time on single data) and filter with core data with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

[Core data provides NSFetchResultController to help with UITableView. I want to sort data with Duration, Depart, Arrival, Price, and Number of stops with ascending and descending orders. 
I con sort data by providing sort descriptor to fetch request.

I just want to know is it best way to create FetchResultController for each sorting?

[image]

Comment: why you not read : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html and use **NSPredicate**

Comment: Yes i can fetch data with predicate but i want to sort data(multiple times) after fetching, So should i use FetchResultController and change request for each sorting or Need to create array of fetched data for sorting. Which one is best?

Comment: why after fatching you shoud fatch with query with sort:)

Comment: I have flights data with depart, Arrival, Number of stops, Price, and journey duration. I need to fetch data from core data. Now user can sort data (Ascending or descending) according price, depart and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create a new fetchedResultsController each time you need to sort. A fetchedResultsController tracks updates, deletes, inserts and moves, so if your data changes after you fetch it, the fetchedResultsController will tell you how to update your view.  If you just do a fetch and then resort the results, the data can get out of date. And worse, if you access an object after it has been deleted your app will crash.  A fetchedResultsController protects you from those issues.

Even with large data sets I have not had any problem creating a new fetchedResultsController every time the user wishes to sort.  If you find that you have performance problems you should deal with it then and not pre-optimize.

Comment: Data never changed once fetched. Sorting done on same data. @jon Rose

Comment: I would still recommend using a fetchedResultsController.  Apps tend to change and get more complex over time.  Setting yourself up to crash whenever an object is deleted when you don't expect it seems to me to be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @ Jon Rose